# While using Safari on my Mac Mini, I subscribed to notifications, but they are not appearing in the Users list in OneSignal

Tags: macos, push-notification, safari, onesignal

Upon a user's visit to my site, I display a popup box, requesting them to subscribe to notifications. Following this, I present the browser's native prompt, seeking permission to allow notifications. However, I have encountered an issue wherein users who subscribe using Safari on Mac do not appear in the OneSignal user list.

I need to show the user in the List of users in Onesignal for sending notifications to them

Follwoing code block is my configuration example

```
let initData = {
     welcomeNotification: {
          disable: true
     },
     appId: app_id,
     safari_web_id: safari_web_id,
     autoResubscribe: true,
     notificationClickHandlerAction: 'navigate',
     notificationClickHandlerMatch: 'origin',
     serviceWorkerParam: { scope: '/' },
     serviceWorkerPath: 'OneSignalSDKWorker.js',
     serviceWorkerUpdaterPath: 'OneSignalSDKWorker.js'
}

await OneSignalReact.init(initData)
```